# Selecting table cell to show new view crashes on iOS7 with "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios7

I am new to iOS development and I wrote an RSS-feed reader in Swift. The feed items are displayed in a UITableView. When I select (touch, click) an item, a new UIView is displayed, showing the feed description of the selected item.

It works on iOS8 but when I try on iOS7, the application crashes and I get the following output:

```
2015-03-06 21:18:50.009 FeedReaderApp[9084:607] -[FeedReaderApp.TableViewController showViewController:sender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be8b100
2015-03-06 21:18:50.012 FeedReaderApp[9084:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FeedReaderApp.TableViewController showViewController:sender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be8b100'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x006a61e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c4d8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00743243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0069650b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x006960ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   FeedReaderApp                        0x000b8068 _TFC12FeedReaderApp19TableViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 1400
    6   FeedReaderApp                        0x000b8139 _TToFC12FeedReaderApp19TableViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView23didSelectRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 89
    7   UIKit                               0x00e1d9a1 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1513
    8   UIKit                               0x00e1db14 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
    9   UIKit                               0x00e2210e __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    10  UIKit                               0x00d510aa ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    11  UIKit                               0x00d51055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    12  UIKit                               0x00d50e76 _afterCACommitHandler + 532
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0066e36e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0066e2bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0064c254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0064b9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0064b7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x043a15ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x043a142b GSEventRun + 104
    20  UIKit                               0x00d33f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    21  FeedReaderApp                        0x000bc6ae top_level_code + 78
    22  FeedReaderApp                        0x000bc6eb main + 43
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x026676d9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here's the code of my UITableViewController, that's handling the selection of a table cell:

```swift
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, MWFeedParserDelegate {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        currentItem = self.items[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem

        let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailView")
        self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
    }
}
```

Thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: This `[FeedReaderApp.TableViewController showViewController:sender:]` tells you that the "message" `showViewController:sender:` was "sent" to an object of class FeedReaderApp.TableViewController .  Ie, that method was called on that object.  This almost always means that the wrong object has somehow gotten into the wrong place.  Most often this is due to simply passing the wrong object type somewhere, but it can also be due to a "zombie" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ios 7 doesn't have the method showViewController, just exist in iOS8

```
if (self.respondsToSelector(Selector("showViewController"))) 
{
   self.showViewController(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
}
else if(self.navigationController.respondsToSelector(Selector("pushViewController")))
{
   self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vs as UIViewController, animated: true)
}
```